# How to pass in template type parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I was having a discussion with a co-worker about templates, and one of things we were talking about is that given a class such as the following, how would you get away with having the switch statement via usage of templates?

```
enum EVersion
{
    Version_1,
    Version_2,
};

class CBar
{
    ...
public:
    EVersion ver;
};

class CFoo
{
    void Reset()
    {
        switch (pBar->ver)
        {
            case Version_1:
                TemplateHelperMethod<Version_1>::DoSomething();
            break;

            case Version_2:
                TemplateHelperMethod<Version_2>::DoSomething();
            break;
        }
    }

    CBar *pBar;
};

CFoo* pFoo = new CFoo(pBar);
pFoo->Reset();
```

One solution is to create a derived templated class, and move the function to the derived class that needs to use a switch statement based on the version.

```
class CFoo
{
    ...
    CBar *pBar;
};

template <EVersion Ver>
class CFoo2 : public Foo
{
    void Reset()
    {
        TemplateHelperMethod<Ver>::DoSomething();
    }
};

CFoo2<Version_2>* pFoo = new CFoo2<Version_2>(pBar);
pFoo->Reset();
```

However, my co-worker suggested that it's possible to keep the original function in the base class, and just change it to a templated method (something like below). However, I am a little dense on how that would work. How would you use the derived class to pass the type to the templated method now? If anyone has any ideas, please let me know. Thanks.

```
class CFoo
{
    template <EVersion Ver>
    void Reset()
    {
        TemplateHelperMethod<Ver>::DoSomething();
    }

    CBar *pBar;
};

template <EVersion Ver>
class CFoo2 : public Foo
{
    // does anything go here?
};

CFoo2<Version_2>* pFoo = new CFoo2<Version_2>(pBar);
pFoo->Reset();

OR

CFoo* pFoo = new CFoo(pBar);
// Can you do this? since CFoo2 derives from CFoo
// and has no additional members...   
CFoo2<Version_2>* pFoo2 = static_cast<CFoo2<Version_2>*>(pFoo);
pFoo2->Reset();
```

Comment: It would add considerable oxygen to the fire of your question if the posted code examples stood a chance of *compiling*. It *almost* looks like you're trying to tag-dispatch, but its difficult to tell.

Comment: Read here and try things out . http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/templated_functions.html

Answer (score 0):

I think what your co-worker suggested is not possible since `pBar->ver` is not a compile time constant. You cannot use it as template parameter.

The correct solution to remove a switch on a runtime variable is runtime polymorphism

```
struct Version
{
    virtual ~Version() = default;
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

class CBar
{
public:
    Version& ver;
};


class CFoo
{
public:
    void Reset()
    {
        pBar->ver.DoSomething();
    }
    CBar *pBar;
};
```

If you make `CBar::ver` a compile time constant you can use it to specialize `CFoo` on it.

```
template<EVersion Version>
struct CBar
{
    EVersion version = Version;
};


template<EVersion Version>
struct CFoo
{
    void Reset();
    CBar<Version> pBar;
};


template<>
void CFoo<Version_1>::Reset()
{
}

template<>
void CFoo<Version_2>::Reset()
{
}
```